# Сортировка списка по числовым значениям

Tags: python, алгоритм, python-3.x

Предположим, есть список `['SLI-1.txt', 'SLI-10.txt', 'SLI-2.txt', 'SLI-3.txt', 'SLI-4.txt', 'SLI-5.txt', 'SLI-6.txt', 'SLI-7.txt', 'SLI-8.txt', 'SLI-9.txt', 'TD-1.txt', 'TD-10.txt', 'TD-2.txt', 'TD-3.txt', 'TD-4.txt', 'TD-5.txt', 'TD-6.txt', 'TD-7.txt', 'TD-8.txt', 'TD-9.txt']`

Как сделать сортировку, чтобы лист выглядел следующим образом?

`['SLI-1.txt', 'SLI-2.txt', 'SLI-3.txt', 'SLI-4.txt', 'SLI-5.txt', 'SLI-6.txt', 'SLI-7.txt', 'SLI-8.txt', 'SLI-9.txt', 'SLI-10.txt', 'TD-1.txt', 'TD-2.txt', 'TD-3.txt', 'TD-4.txt', 'TD-5.txt', 'TD-6.txt', 'TD-7.txt', 'TD-8.txt', 'TD-9.txt','TD-10.txt']`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

достаточно написать свою функцию для сортировки:

```
def smth_sort(data):
    return data[:data.index('-')], int(data[data.index('-') + 1:data.index('.')])

a = ['SLI-1.txt', 'SLI-10.txt', 'SLI-2.txt', 'SLI-3.txt', 'SLI-4.txt', 'SLI-5.txt', 'SLI-6.txt', 'SLI-7.txt', 'SLI-8.txt', 'SLI-9.txt', 'TD-1.txt', 'TD-10.txt', 'TD-2.txt', 'TD-3.txt', 'TD-4.txt', 'TD-5.txt', 'TD-6.txt', 'TD-7.txt', 'TD-8.txt', 'TD-9.txt']

sorted(a, key=smth_sort)

# ['SLI-1.txt', 'SLI-2.txt', 'SLI-3.txt', 'SLI-4.txt', 'SLI-5.txt', 'SLI-6.txt', 'SLI-7.txt', 'SLI-8.txt', 'SLI-9.txt', 'SLI-10.txt', 'TD-1.txt', 'TD-2.txt', 'TD-3.txt', 'TD-4.txt', 'TD-5.txt', 'TD-6.txt', 'TD-7.txt', 'TD-8.txt', 'TD-9.txt', 'TD-10.txt']
```